# script to grep a pattern in a file and perform an arithmetic operation from the extracted string

Tags: bash

I am a novice at scripting so looking for some pointers as to how to solve my problem.

There is a log file (server.log) which keeps track of the number of connections being made to a database .

Pattern to grep
"error number 1**(this number will be from 1-30000)** on 30000 possible before the block"

what i need to do is perform an arithmetic operation on the numbers, need the difference so in the above example 30000-1 =29999 . based on the result i will need to print a Warning or Critical message.

If difference is less that 10,000 then it will result in a warning and if it is more than 10,000 it will be critical.

Thanks,
K

Comment: I don't get it, warning if less than 10k remaining, critical if more than 10k remaining ?

Comment: @tensibai , the threshold limit is 30k and the log file captures each entry starting from 1 going upto 30k. Let me know if that explains my question better.

Comment: The unclear part is probably that 30 000 - 10 000 = 20 000, so 15 000 (more than 10 000) is critical, but 25 000 is just a warning?

Comment: @ILikeMatDotH, ok i see the confusion now. This excerpt is from a log file that captures incoming connections to a web module where the max permissible connection limit is 30k. The program is designed in such a way that when the connection limit reaches 30k no new connections are allowed and the system will go into  a blocked state.

Comment: So I am trying to set an alarm which will notify us once its nearing 10k as a warning and then once it crosses 10k start sending critical . I understand that its not an ideal way to do it but that how we received the request

Comment: See my edited answer, "is it getting better or do you feel the same"? If you try to tell me more about how logs are formatted maybe we could figure something out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

My assumption: You have a file with lines containing numbers in range 1-30000, let us say that, if you have 1-10000 you are fine, 10 - 20 000 is warning, 20 - 30 000 is critical. You do not need an arithmetic operation for matching number size you can use regex:

e.g.:

```
$ grep -E '2[0-9]{4}' file >/dev/null && echo "Critical"
$ grep -E '1[0-9]{4}' file >/dev/null && echo "Warning"
```

First line matches 20000 - 29999 and prints Critical, for 10 000 - 19 999 outputs Warning. 0 -  9 999 outputs nothing, but it could, it would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

more_than_2k=$(grep -E '2[0-9]{4}' file)

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ] ; then
  echo "Critical"
else
  more_than_1k=$(grep -E '1[0-9]{4}')
  if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "Warning"
  else
    echo "Nothing happens"
  fi
fi
```

Or you could specify it exactly (note that 4 or less digit number is contained in 5digit number so you cannot say `grep -E '[0-9]{1,4}' file` but you can specify a surrounding (in case of log that should be pretty easy).

Or you can use awk:

```
$ cat file
9000
900
900
900
800
18000
1900

$ awk '{ if ($1 > 8000 &&  $1 < 10000)
  print "warn"
  else if ($1 > 10000)
  print "crit" }' file

warn
crit
```

EDIT:

you can add to grep a prefix and suffix:

```
$ cat file 
error number 9000 on 30000 possible block
error number 900 on 30000 possible block
error number 900 on 30000 possible block
error number 900 on 30000 possible block
error number 800 on 30000 possible block
error number 18000 on 30000 possible block
error number 1900 on 30000 possible block

$ grep -E 'error number 1[0-9]{4} on 30000 possible block' file
error number 18000 on 30000 possible block

$ awk '{ if ($3 > 8000 &&  $3 < 10000)
  print "warn"
  else if ($3 > 10000)
  print "crit" }' file
warn
crit
```

Comment: the grep does not help as there are multiple numeric entries in the log file which are over 5 digits so the grep would always return critical messages.

Comment: if anything need to first grep the pattern "error number 29987 on 30000 possible before the block" and then create a critical or warning message based on the number in that result pattern

Comment: ` grep -E 'error number 1[0-9]{4} on 30000 possible block' file>/dev/null && echo "Warning"
` does it, or you could just grep the pattern: `grep -E "error number [0-9]{1,5} on 30000 possible before the block"` and pipe it to something else, it is up to you

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to use part of the solution you mentioned above in my script. But then got a different requirement all together.